# Convert excel to json python

Tags: python, jupyter

I have an excel sheet with two columns and I want to convert it into json. 
[image]

I want to convert this into a json format like this:

```
{"A": "This is a Sentence", "B": "1"},
{"A": "This is a Sentence", "B": "2"},
{"A": "This is a Sentence", "B": "3"},
{"A": "This is a Sentence", "B": "4"}
```

I tried using this command:

```
data= df.to_json (r'C:\Users\Admin\df_json.json',orient='split')
```

but it generates something like this:

```
[{"A": "This is a Sentence", "B": "1"},{"A": "This is a Sentence", "B": "2"},{"A": "This is a Sentence", "B": "3"},{"A": "This is a Sentence", "B": "4"},]
```

Comment: So that is same. Isn't it?

Comment: No, it is generated as a list,inside a square bracket. I don't want the square bracket.

Answer (score 2):

The result you are getting is normal json. What you described as your desired result is *json lines* (also called *jsonlines*, *jsonl* or similar). There's no built-in support for it as far as I know, but if you want to output json lines it's pretty easy to do by hand. Here's an example on how you would write json lines to a file:

```
data = df.to_json (r'C:\Users\Admin\df_json.json', orient='split')
with open("converted.jsonl", mode="wt", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for line in data:
        f.write(json.dumps(line) + "\n")
```

Comment: this gives an error: "'NoneType' object is not iterable" at line 3 which means 'data' is of type None. Am I doing something wrong ?